# Corrosive potential of molten ionic salt

Tags: metal, salt, corrosion

I was looking at this video about fourth generation of nuclear reactors and one of developing concepts is molten salt reactor (MSR) where melted ionic salt replaces water as coolant and also acts as a solvent for nuclear fuel. This has many advantages regarding safety and efficiency but one question always arises - corrosion of steel tubing with high temperature molten salt. The response of one developer was that this questions is based of a false extrapolation of everyday experience where we see car metals are attacked when exposed to snow/road salt. [He says](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pqVt8cxx-44&t=837s) that the mixture of water and salt has the greatest corrosive potential and in fact, pure molten salt is less corrosive not only from the mixture but also than the pure water. Is that generally true for ionic salts (salt in question is sodium chloride) or is it maybe true only for specific salt/temperature range?

Comment: Water is corrosive because of $\ce{H+}$; molten salt doesn't have that.

Comment: @IvanNeretin So, you think his claim is false?

Comment: No, I think the claim is true. Pure molten NaCl must be less corrosive than water.

Comment: A seriously researched subject ;  Try NACE ( National association of Corrosion Engineers)  references if interested . Molten salts are also used to heat-treat steels .

Comment: Does he state which kind of salt is picked? Probably not *organic* ionic liquids. Don't forget that there equally is the sodium-cooled approach (e.g., French Superphénix) of fast breeders ...

Comment: Indeed, the larger problem is what happens if the pipes cool too much with molten salts in them...

Comment: Molten salt reactors use specific mixtures of salts (often LiF/BeF2 mixtures). They have been widely researched so their corrosive potential is well known (or the lack of it). Besides, the comparison is with reactors using high pressure steam (PWRs) and that is not a system with zero potential to corrode the pipework. Given this, there is little concern that well-chosen salts will have high corrosion potential.

Comment: @matt_black Well, that is true for thermal reactors. The reactor in question is actually fast reactor and uses molten sodium chloride.